# FactoryGirl not passing arguments in build

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, factory-bot

I have a ruby app that I'm using rspec and factorygirl with, and I'm having trouble building a factory. When I run the spec, I get an `ArgumentError: missing keywords` for the required keywords in initialize. If I pass them in explicitly, the error changes to `wrong number of arguments 0 for 2`.

Thanks for any help on this.

**spec/models/player_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Player do

  it 'has a valid factory' do
    player = build(:player) # or build(:player, name: 'testname', password: 'testpw')
  end
end
```

**spec/factories/player.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :player do
    name     { 'Testname' }
    password { 'testpass' }
  end
end
```

**models/player.rb**

```
def initialize(name:, password:)
  @id       = object_id
  @name     = name
  @password = password
end
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the error traces?

Comment: Do your keywords have to be required or can you do this: `def initialize(name: nil, password: nil)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this to work by changing the player#initialize method to accept an options hash instead of keyword arguments params.

Comment: This is not actually the solution, but a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Change your **spec/factories/player.rb** with:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :player do
    name      'Testname'
    password  'testpass'

    initialize_with { new(name:name, password: password) }
  end
end
```

You can find the documentation [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Custom_Construction) although is not explicit to be used in this case.

Comment: Thanks! This solved it for me (Rails 4.2.3, Ruby 2.2.2).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the syntax that they recommend on the github repo Read Me? 
It looks like defining a factory is done with the following syntax:

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :player do 
    name 'Testname' 
    password 'testpass'
  end
end
```

They may be equivalent, but this stood out to me as being a potential problem. It seems that blocks are used whenever you are executing logic, not declaring.

Comment: The blocks are unnecessary in this case, but they're valid. A block can be used to calculate attributes at build time, rather than at the time the factory is defined.